During a Git merge conflict resolution, can I check out the conflicting state of a file?
When git merge has conflicts, the files that are in a conflicting state contain markers showing the differences.
Suppose that while trying to resolve a conflict, I've made changes, perhaps:

Taking some lines from main and some from mybranch
Running git checkout mybranch somefile, thinking "I'll just use the version that's on mybranch

But then I have second thoughts, and I want to put the file back the way it was at the start of the merge, showing the conflict markers, and start over trying to resolve the conflicts.
I'm guessing I can run git checkout [something] somefile to get back to the conflicting state. What would it be?

Use the --merge option (-m in short form) for git checkout or git restore (both commands behave the same here)
# the legacy way
git checkout -m <path>

# the (not so) new way
git restore -m <path>


With -m, changes made to the working tree file can be discarded to re-create the original conflicted merge result.


Nice! The simplest way.

git checkout --conflict=merge somefile
Found it in the manual. The other options for --conflict are diff3 and zdiff3, as in:
git checkout --conflict=diff3 <path>
Update: git checkout -m <path, as @RomainValeri suggested, is the simplest option; this is similar but the different --conflict strategies provide a bit more control.

Never stumbled upon this one syntax, but it seems that both our solutions work the same. Good to know.
